# What sort of SBC is in the C64 Maxi?

Tags: commodore-64, arm

Curious as to what model SBC this unit is using

https://retrogames.biz/thec64

8 bit guys teardown says the internals are 'an ARM computer similar to a Raspberry Pi'

https://youtu.be/kxx2F4ffmeE

Comment: The Mini is Allwinner A20 dual core; I haven’t a Maxi so can but speculate from there.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion: [Are questions about devices such as the new Commodore 64 Mini on topic here?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/612/278).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 so is your opinion on-topic or off? Seems a bit open to interpretation

Comment: @dashnick Personally, I think it's off-topic, since you're just asking a question about the modern hardware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [a forum post](http://thec64community.online/thread/426/inside-thec64-maxi):

> THEC64 Mainboard is based on this development board
>
> Rocket64
>
> ...
>
> ROCK64 is a credit card size 4K60P HDR Media Board Computer powered by *Rockchip RK3328 Quad-Core ARM Cortex A53 64-Bit Processor [...]

Further details are in that post, and the development board it is referring to appears to be [this one](https://www.pine64.org/devices/single-board-computers/rock64/) though the board from the C64 Maxi looks like a unique design, adding a heatsink and what appear to be solder pads for 9-pin joystick ports (presumably repurposing the GPIO) and omitting an ethernet connector (though it looks like that's what the other solder pad is for?).

That should give you some decent information on the chipset though.

EDIT: here's a direct reproduction of the high-resolution image from that forum thread, in case somebody who is better at this stuff wants to verify my guesses about solder pads:

[image: C64 Maxi main board]

Comment: Thanks! Be curious how much memory / storage is on board if you come across...

Comment: The two identical pads on the left at the bottom don't look like they're for DE-9 joystick connectors as there's only 4 pins. I assume they're USB ports and that they're for the C64 Mini PCB configuration which has two USB ports and button (the top pad) on the right side. The left most pad on the top edge is probably for a power connector.

Comment: Oh, the rectangles at the top and bottom aren’t additional solder points? That made me count 6, which with a common ground is correct, but obviously is also correct for many, many other things. I think you’re right and I’m wrong, regardless.

Answer (score 6):

### THE C64 Maxi Specs

- CPU: Allwinner H3 Quad-core Cortex-A7 @1.29GHz
- GPU: Mali400MP2 GPU @600mhz
- 256MB Memory
- 2GB FMND2G08U3J NAND Chip

From [here](https://thec64community.online/thread/426/inside-thec64-maxi).